# Pandas get unique values from a column and only latest date efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
NonUniqueKey       Date
1111              01-01-2020  12:00
4444              22-09-2020  14:00
1111              23-07-2020  04:00
2222              08-03-2020  08:15
2222              08-03-2020  08:16 
2222              08-03-2020  08:17
3333              11-11-2019  00:00
```

Expected output :

```
NonUniqueKey       Date
4444              22-09-2020  14:00
1111              23-07-2020  04:00
2222              08-03-2020  08:17
3333              11-11-2019  00:00
```

I want to get unique `NonUniqueKey` value of the latest `Date` only. I'm using `drop_duplicates(subset ='NonUniqueKey')`, removed the duplicate but wrong value taken..

Comment: First convert values to datetimes and then use any of solutions.

Comment: But how to make sure the other column is unique?? HOW IS THIS DUPLICATE?? your comment isnt useful either

Comment: OK, use`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)` and then  `df.loc[df.groupby('NonUniqueKey')['Date'].idxmax()]`